# Prove generalized arithmetic relationship between sum of products and product of sums

Tags: summation, arithmetic, products

In a math book the following equation is used (without proof). Assuming it is correct (at least for n=1,2,3 it seems to be), how can I prove it?
$$\prod_{i=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^n a_k^i = \sum_{k_1,\dots,k_n=1}^n \prod_{i=1}^n a_{k_i}^i$$
I assume the proof has to be done with induction. But I find it extremely complicated to prove the induction step from n to n+1. I regularly get lost somewhere in the middle of the conversion process. Can someone give a hint for a good strategy or for how to find a good strategy? (I cannot find a proof anywhere in a book or in the net. Does anyone know any?)

Note: The i denotes a superscript of a, not a power of a. Sorry, this was a bit misleading. I should have used 2 subscripts.

Comment: Hint: in inductive proofs it sometimes helps to strengthen the induction hypothesis by trying to prove something more general.  Here you might try making the sum on the left-hand side of the equation go from $1$ to $m$ rather than $1$ to $n$. When you've figured out what the right-hand side should be, you should find this easier to prove by induction than the original problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There $n^n$ terms on both sides. It will not be easy to link $(n+1)^{n+1}$ back to $n^n$. So Induction would be difficult.

The LHS is
\begin{eqnarray*}
(a_1+a_2+ \cdots +a_n)(a_1^2+a_2^2+ \cdots +a_n^2) \cdots (a_1^i+a_2^i+ \cdots +a_n^i)\cdots (a_1^n+a_2^n+ \cdots +a_n^n)
\end{eqnarray*}
A general term when you expand this is 
\begin{eqnarray*}
a_{k_1}a_{k_2} \cdots a_{k_i}^i\cdots a_{k_n}^{n} = \prod_{i=1}^{n} a_{k_i}^i
\end{eqnarray*}
where each $k_i$ will range over $1$ to $n$.
So we just need to put in these summations & we have 
\begin{eqnarray*}
 \sum_{k_1=1}^{n} \sum_{k_2=1}^{n} \cdots\sum_{k_i=1}^{n} \cdots\sum_{k_n=1}^{n} \prod_{i=1}^{n} a_{k_i}^i
\end{eqnarray*}